# Animate rectangle height increase/decrease?

Tags: c, animation, opengl, glut, opengl-compat

I want to know how can I make an animation that represents a rectangle with height increase/decrease in OpenGL. I know I'm supposed to use the glScale and glTranslate functions.

Below, I will attach the code that I've worked with so far, where I managed to apply a pretty basic transition of a rectangle.

```cpp
#include <windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include <GL/glut.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static GLfloat trans = 0.0;

void init(void)
{
    glClearColor(0.2, 0.2, 0.2, 0.2);
    glShadeModel(GL_FLAT);
}
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0 , trans, 1.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    glRectf(-25.0, -25.0, 25.0, 25.0);
    glPopMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    glRectf(-15.0, -15.0, 15.0, 15.0);
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
void transLeft(void)
{
    trans = trans - 0.05;
    if (trans < -75)
        trans = -75;
    glutPostRedisplay();
}
void transRight(void)
{
    trans = trans + 0.05;
    if (trans > 75)
        trans = 75;

    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void reshape(int w, int h)
{
    glViewport(0, 0, (GLsizei)w, (GLsizei)h);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-100.0, 100.0, -100.0, 100.0, -1.0, 1.0);
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
    glLoadIdentity();
}
void mouse(int button, int state, int x, int y)
{
    switch (button) {
    case GLUT_LEFT_BUTTON:
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
            glutIdleFunc(transLeft);
        break;
    case GLUT_RIGHT_BUTTON:
        if (state == GLUT_DOWN)
            glutIdleFunc(transRight);
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB);
    glutInitWindowSize(500, 500);
    glutInitWindowPosition(100, 100);
    glutCreateWindow(argv[0]);
    init();
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutReshapeFunc(reshape);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    glutMainLoop();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: either change the hard coded coordinates in `glRect` to variables or put `glScalef(zoom,zoom,1.0)`  just after or before the `glTranslate` in your display function (where depends on what you want to achieve), note it might require to change the translation values (multiply or divide by `zoom`)  where `zoom=1.0` is variable for changing the size ... update it by `zoom*=1.025` or `zoom/=1.025` for inc/dec size ... on some keyboard hit or mouse wheel or whatever ...

Comment: A piece of code or something like that won't hurt me or anything, but that's ok if you don't have the time or simply just don't want to. I'm still not able to make it work and I think I could understand better if you could post an actual code line.

Comment: @EmanuelComan Actually there is a line of code in the comment `glScalef(zoom,zoom,1.0)`. You can use separate scales for x and y: `glScalef(zoom_x, zoom_x,1.0)`. Change `zoom_x` and `zoom_y` by time. Try values in range [0.5, 1.5].

Comment: Yea I know, but I tried that but it still didn't work, and I was wondering if I should add anything else besides this command. Also I'm not really sure where am I supposed to put that command in my code.

Comment: @EmanuelComan You have to add `glScale` after `glTranslatef`

Comment: I think I figured it out, but is there any way that I can make the scaling work just in a direction, because right now the animation is going both upwards and downwards

Comment: @EmanuelComan An alternative solution is to use variables for the coordinates `glRectf(x0, y0, x1, y1);`. Change on of the coordinates by time.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to have variable height rectangle (based on what?).

Yes `glScale(1.0,zoom,1.0)` placed directly before or after the line

```
glTranslatef(0.0 , trans, 1.0);
```

In your `display(void)` function will do this. Where zoom is holding your animation state and is starting with value `zoom=1.0` and to change size you just increment/decrement like this: `zoom*=1.025 or zoom/=1.025`.

However its usually better to interchange your hard-coded rectangle vertexes with variable ones based on parameter or time or whatever you want to change this with. That way you can interpolate between min and max rectangle size with parameter without changing the matrices which might pose a problem with other objects if you not careful And also this way provides more convenient control of the animation. For example you have:

```
glRectf(-25.0, -25.0, 25.0, 25.0);
```

And want to animate it to size:

```
glRectf(-25.0, -35.0, 25.0, 35.0);
```

over time so you can do this like this:

1. **add some global or static variables holding your rectangle sizes and position and animation state:**

   ```
                  // x0, y0beg, y0end,   x1,y1beg,y1end
   float myrec[]={-25.0, -25.0, -35.0, 25.0, 25.0, 35.0}; 
   float t=0.0; // parameter in range <0.0,1.0>
   ```
2. **in display compute your rectangle actual coordinates and render**

   You can use linear interpolation like this:

   ```
   glRectf(myrect[0],myrect[1]+((myrect[2]-myrect[1])*t),
           myrect[3],myrect[4]+((myrect[5]-myrect[4])*t));
   ```
3. **set you `t` for animation somewhere**

   Where depends on what you want to achieve... If you have timer or some call that si repeated again and again you can increment the t in it by some step for example:

   ```
   t+=dt/T;
   if (t>1.0) t=1.0; // use t=0.0; if you want to repeat the animation after it finishes
   ```

   Where `dt` is the avg time your call is repeated with and `T` is the time of whole animation finish. I do not use GLUT so I just assume your Display is called repeatedly (for example 60 times per second) and want the animation to finish in 2 sec then:

   ```
   // dt = 1.0/60
   // T  = 2.0
   t+=(1.0/120.0);
   if (t>1.0) t=1.0; // use t=0.0; if you want to repeat the animation after it
   ```

   You can also use elapsed time (by measuring it by some OS or environment function you have at your disposal I usually use performance timer/counters on windows) from last call instead of `dt`.

If you have more of such rectangles you can encapsulate this to some function and simply call it with pointer to its `myrect` values and parameter `t` for example:

```
void draw_rect(float *myrec,float t)
   {
   glRectf(myrect[0],myrect[1]+((myrect[2]-myrect[1])*t),
           myrect[3],myrect[4]+((myrect[5]-myrect[4])*t));
   }

float rec0[]={-25.0, -25.0, -35.0, 25.0, 25.0, 35.0}; 
float rec1[]={-15.0, -15.0, -25.0, 15.0, 15.0, 25.0}; 
float t=0.0; // parameter in range <0.0,1.0>
void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    glPushMatrix();
    glTranslatef(0.0 , trans, 1.0);
    glColor3f(1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
    draw_rect(rec0,t);
    glPopMatrix();
    glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    draw_rect(rec1,t);
    glutSwapBuffers();

    t+=(1.0/120.0);
    if (t>1.0) t=0.0;
}
```